# Converted PDF to Base64 string representation not openable when converted back

Tags: xml, vba, excel, pdf

I need to have a PDF converted into a base 64 string such that I can send it in an XML file. I am using an excel spreadsheet to store all the data we need to go into the XML and then some VBA code that prints the XML to a file. The recipient of said XML file cannot open my PDFs. Adobe says it is either not a .pdf file or it is corrupt. I did some extra code to test my original conversion and I am getting the same problem also. The XSD specifies that data should be of type xsd:base64Binary

The first function is to generate the string that gets sent off as XML. The second function is called from the first function and is purely for my testing purposes.

I have found this code on other stackoverflow threads and pieced it together from a few sources, but it differs slightly in the different constant values used (e.g. "Base64Data", "b64" and "Base64" are all inputs I have seen for objXML.createElement). I also have a feeling I have gotten the text/binary and read/write functions in reverse order. A string is generated that looks very much like base64 binary, although there are some parts that look suspiciously repetative when I had a quick scan through the produced XML.

```
Function processBase64Binary(ByVal filePath As String) As String

'define objects used
Dim mstream As Stream
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

'load the data from the filepath provided
Set mstream = New Stream
mstream.Type = adTypeBinary
mstream.Open
mstream.LoadFromFile filePath

'convert to base 64 binary and convert to a string to be used in XML
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.nodeTypedValue = mstream.Read()
myText = objNode.Text
testDecode (myText)
processBase64Binary = myText

End Function

Sub testDecode(ByVal strData As String)

Dim mstream As Stream
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.Text = strData
decodeBase64 = objNode.nodeTypedValue

Set mstream = New Stream
mstream.Type = adTypeText
mstream.Open
mstream.WriteText (strData)
mstream.SaveToFile ("D:\tested5.pdf")

End Sub
```

Comment: `decodeBase64` is your decoded content, not `strData`. So `mstream.WriteText (decodeBase64)`.

Comment: Ah, great find! Unfortunately, that was not the solution. The PDF is still unreadable, and that code has no effect on the end user who receives the PDF. But I will keep having a look taking into it with consideration I made that mistake!